# cost on blocked operation was increased by the number of thread

Tags: c, multithreading, optimization

I've written a program that executes some calculations and then merges the results.

I've used multi-threading to calculate in parallel.

During the phase of merge result, each thread will lock the global array, and then append individual part to it, and some extra work will be done to eliminate the repetitions.

I test it and find that the cost on merging increases with the number of threads, and the rate is unexpected:

2 thread: 40,116,084(us)
6 thread:511,791,532(us)

Why: what occurs when the number of threads increases? How do I change this?

--------------------------slash line -----------------------------------------------------

Actually, the code was very simply, there is the pseudo-code:

typedef my_object{
 
long no;
 
int count;
double value;
 
//something others 
} my_object_t;

static my_object_t** global_result_array; //about ten thounds

static pthread_mutex_t global_lock;

void* thread_function(void* arg){ 
my_object_t** local_result;
int local_result_number;
 
int i;
 
my_object_t* ptr;
 
for(;;){
 
if( exit_condition ){ return NULL;}
 
if( merge_condition){
//start time point to log
 
pthread_mutex_lock( &global_lock);
 
for( i = local_result_number-1; i>=0 ;i++){
 
ptr = local_result[ i] ;
 
if( NULL == global_result_array[ ptr->no] ){
 
global_result_array[ ptr->no] = ptr; //step 4 
}else{ 
global_result_array[ ptr->no] -> count += ptr->count; // step 5 
global_result_array[ ptr->no] -> value += ptr->value; // step 6 
}
 
}
 
pthread_mutex_unlock( &global_lock); // end time point to log 
}else{ 
//do some calculation and produce the partly and thread-local result ,namely the local_result and local_result_number 
}
 
}
 
}

As above, the difference between two threads and six threads are step 5 and step6, i has counted that there were about hundreds millions order of execution of step 5 and 6. The others are same.
So, from my view, the merge operation was very light, in spite of using 2 thread or 6 thread, they both need to lock and do merge exclusively.
Another astonished thing was : when using six thread, the cost on step 4 was boomed! It was the boot reason that the total cost was boomed!

btw: The test server has two cpus ,each cpu has four cores.

Answer (score 1):

There are various reasons for the behaviour shown:

1. More threads means more locks and more blocking time among threads. As is apparent from your description, your implementation uses mutex locks or something similar. The speed-up with threads is better if the data sets are largely exclusive.
2. Unless your system has as many processors/cores as the number of threads, all of them cannot run concurrently. You can set the maximum concurrency using `pthread_setconcurrency`.

Answer (score 0):

Context switching is an overhead. Hence the difference. If your computer had 6 cores it would be faster. Overwise you need to have more context switches for the threads.

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge performance difference between 2/6 threads.  I'm sorry, but you have to try very hard indeed to make such a huge discrepancy.  You seem to have succeeded:((

As others have pointed out, using multiple threads on one data set only becomes worth it if the time spent on inter-thread communication, (locks etc.), is less than the time gained by the concurrent operations.

If, for example, you find that you are merging successively smaller data sections, (eg. with a merge sort), you are effectively optimizing the time wasted on inter-thread comms and cache-thrashing. This is why multi-threaded merge-sorts are frequently started with an in-place sort once the data has been divided up into a chunk less than the size of the L1 cache.

'each thread will lock the global array' - try to not do this.  Locking large data structures for extended periods, or continually locking them for successive short periods, is a very bad plan.  Locking the global once serializes the threads and generates one thread with too much inter-thread comms.  Continualy locking/releasing generates one thread with far, far too much inter-thread comms.

Once the operations get so short that the returns are diminished to the point of uselessness, you would be better off queueing those operations to one thread that finishes off the job on its own.

Locking is often grossly over-used and/or misused.  If I find myself locking anything for longer than the time taken to push/pop a pointer onto a queue or similar, I start to get jittery..

Without seeing/analysing the code, and more importantly, data,, (I guess both are complex), it's difficult to give any direct advice:(

Comment: Thanks James, I has post the sketch of my code, review it please.